# In rails when trying to create a association with the attribute `model_name`, I get this error ' undefined method `human' for nil:NilClass'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When trying to create a association using nested forms, I get this error ' undefined method `human' for nil:NilClass' The problem is, I don't have any method called`human`.

The specific attribute that gives the problem is `model_name` :

```
def model_name
    model.try(:name)
end

def model_name=(name)
    self.model = Model.find_or_create_by name: name if name.present?
end
```

Here's the stack trace and the source code files :
https://gist.github.com/THPubs/19aae5239f0e417c0f1d

What might be the problem?

Comment: From the stack trace, it looks like the issue is related to the warden gem.  Double check that you are installing and configuring it properly.

Comment: @steveklein Found the answer :-) The method `model_name` have been conflicting with rails built in methods. Changed the name and things are working now! Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: Lol I was wondering about that but didn't find model_name on the list of [reserved Rails words](https://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/) I checked.  Glad you solved it.

Comment: @steveklein Just a lucky hunch. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `model_name` conflicts with rails' own `model_name` method which have a method called `human` which according to the docs `Transform the model name into a more humane format, using I18n. By default, it will underscore then humanize the class name.`.

After changing the method name to `vehicle_model_name` everything worked fine!